# Ionic 4 doesn't open target page when tap Push Notification on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm developing an Ionic app and I have an issue with FCM push notifications on iOS. I can send the notification when the app is on background or foreground, but not when the app is opened. Also, after I tap the notification, it doesn't redirect to another page of the app and only show root page (in Android works very well).

So, in iOS I need to retrieve notification data and redirect properly.

This is an Ionic v4 app with Android and iOS builded code. I use this piece of code to get the notification data

```
this._fcm.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(
            msg => {
                (this.platform.is('ios')) ? ((msg.aps && msg.aps.alert) ? this._toast.presentToast(msg.aps.alert) : this._toast.presentToast(msg.body)) : this._toast.presentToast(msg.body);

                if (msg.title && msg.title === '¡Ayuda!' && msg.origin) {
                    this._fcm.getData('token', msg.origin).subscribe(
                        (res: any) => {
                            this.getContactData(res);
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
```

In getData function I get some data on Firebase with a token. This token is setted in notification data, so when I get the data in res, the getContactData function takes res values and redirect to help page with the contact data.

But when I debug the builded iOS code, I get these errors in Xcode console:

```
2019-07-09 00:58:33.317597-0400 MuniConceApp[1469:254931] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/)
2019-07-09 00:58:33.343859-0400 MuniConceApp[1469:254915] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
```

Notification image:

[image]

In this image the notification is shown on iOS, but when I tap this notification, the help page doesn't open and only show the root page (home).

Comment: Can you show the code for getContactData() function?

Comment: Hi @SunnyParekh, this is the code for getContactData function: https://jsfiddle.net/46pdbo1q/

Please look at javascript field.

Comment: not able to open the fiddle!

Comment: I access it now and could not find any logic that is redirecting you to the Help Page! I guess you need to help us with the actual redirection logic! This does not display the clear picture!

Comment: This is the app component fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4npteqo/. In this fiddle you'll find the function which redirect to "receive-help" page